# Powershell output for Microsoft Defender status

Tags: powershell, intune, windows-defender

I'm very new to PowerShell and I have a question in regards to Microsoft Intune and PowerShell.

I have this `GetMPComputerStatus|select AMRunning` to check if Defender is "Normal" or "Passive", that's the only two outcomes.

How do I make an if or search statement so I can get all the devices which returns "Passive"?

Comment: Will this be running against remote computers?

Comment: Yes, it will be running against remote computers via Intune

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say *"get all the devices which returns "Passive""*, I assume you need to check different computers and filter out all that have their antimalware software not in "Normal" mode.

For that you can use the `-CimSession` parameter that allows you to enter (an array) of computernames to test.

```
$computers = 'PC01', 'PC02', 'PC03'                # the computers you need to check
Get-MpComputerStatus -CimSession $computers | 
Where-Object {$_.AMRunningMode -eq 'Passive' } |   # or use Where-Object {$_.AMRunningMode -ne 'Normal' }
Select-Object PsComputerName, AMRunningMode
```

Comment: Yes, I need to check different computers and filter out the ones who are in "Passive" mode.
Thanks for the tip, I will have a look at it, and see how it works :)
Thanks for your time

Comment: I don't need to define the computers I will be checking on though. So I don't think i need $computers ?

Comment: @ProgramToddler Of course you can do different things if you like. Using `$computers` was just as example how you could make use of the fact that the `-CimSession` parameters can take an array of computernames. You could also loop through a series of computers one-at-a-time if you like that better.

Comment: I am thankful for you help - I'm sorry if it sounds like I don't appreciate your answer!

Comment: @ProgramToddler No it is nothing like that, It is just something most new users are not aware of, so that's why I have this rather standard comment in cases like that to point that out. Once accepted, an answer will show up green when someone else is searching for a similar thing and that helps in finding it. No offence taken, really!

Comment: Arh okay. Thanks for explaining to me how it works! And thanks for your help